# How to create PDF Template using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

My task is to create a PDF template which contains multiple pages and multiple tables. Below is code I wrote to create a table. I don't know how to create a template of that table.
When I change the value of `pageSize.GetLeft(40), pageSize.GetBottom(200)`, there is no effect in the template.

```cs
Rectangle pageSize = document.PageSize;

Department = "Town Development Department";
WebSite = "www.cmdachennai.gov.in";
VersionNumber = "1.0.77";

Phrase cc = new Phrase("This is report", H2);
Paragraph hp = new Paragraph();
hp.Add(cc);

Phrase c1 = new Phrase("Check List Report", H5);

Phrase c2 = new Phrase("Report Generated On : ", H3);
Phrase c3 = new Phrase(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), H3);

Phrase c5 = new Phrase("Version Number : ", H3);
Phrase c6 = new Phrase(VersionNumber, H3);

//Phrase c7 = new Phrase("Version Number : ", H3);

Paragraph hp4 = new Paragraph();
hp4.Add(c5);
hp4.Add(c6);

Paragraph hp1 = new Paragraph();
hp1.Add(c2);
hp1.Add(c3);


hp.Alignment = 1;
PdfPTable tblTopHeading = new PdfPTable(1);
tblTopHeading.WidthPercentage = 100;
PdfPCell Topcell = new PdfPCell();
Topcell.AddElement(hp);
Topcell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
Topcell.BorderWidthBottom = 0f;
Topcell.BorderWidthLeft = 0f;
Topcell.BorderWidthRight = 0f;
Topcell.BorderWidthTop = 0f;

tblTopHeading.AddCell(Topcell);
document.Add(tblTopHeading);

Paragraph hp2 = new Paragraph(Department, H4);
Paragraph hp3 = new Paragraph(WebSite, H4);
Phrase c = new Phrase("\n", H4);
PdfPTable tblHeading = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 100f, 60f });
tblHeading.WidthPercentage = 100;
PdfPCell cell_1 = new PdfPCell();
PdfPCell cell_2 = new PdfPCell();

Paragraph hp5 = new Paragraph();
hp5.Add(c1);
//hp5.Add(c2);

cell_1.AddElement(hp5);

hp1.Alignment = 2;
hp2.Alignment = 2;
hp3.Alignment = 2;
hp4.Alignment = 2;

cell_2.AddElement(hp1);
cell_2.AddElement(hp4);

cell_1.BorderWidthBottom = 0f;
cell_1.BorderWidthLeft = 0f;
cell_1.BorderWidthRight = 0f;
cell_1.BorderWidthTop = 0f;
cell_2.BorderWidthBottom = 0f;
cell_2.BorderWidthLeft = 0f;
cell_2.BorderWidthRight = 0f;
cell_2.BorderWidthTop = 0f;

tblHeading.AddCell(cell_1);
tblHeading.AddCell(cell_2);
document.Add(tblHeading);

cb.AddTemplate(template, pageSize.GetLeft(40), pageSize.GetBottom(200));
```

Comment: What does *"template"* imply for you? Shall there be some way to replace or fill in some sections or fields? How dynamic shall it be?

Comment: yes there should be value in cell which come from form but i just want to create template of table value should be change according to form filled data

Comment: Editing regular text content in pdfs can be difficult. Filling in form field on the other hand is easy. Thus, I would suggest working with form fields.

Comment: In your code you call `cb.AddTemplate(template, ...)` but that variable `template` is mentioned nowhere before. As this also is the line for which you discuss effects of changes of the other parameters, you should explain what `template` is and contains.

Comment: variable declare ```PdfTemplate template;``` and  in  OnOpenDocument method ```template = cb.CreateTemplate(300, 800);```  is create template

Comment: Ok, so you create a `PdfTemplate` in that variable. But do you put anything on that template? If you don't, then it is not surprising that adding that template at different positions makes no difference because an empty template effectively is invisible. Maybe you should explain what you expect adding an empty `PdfTemplate` results in.

Comment: can you explain how to put table in ``` pdftemplate``` because right now i just create template

Comment: First of all, what is that `cb` you add the template to? It's defined nowhere either...

Comment: Did my answer help? Or are there still open questions?

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out in comments, the template you add to `cb` (whatever `cb` may be) here

```
cb.AddTemplate(template, pageSize.GetLeft(40), pageSize.GetBottom(200));
```

is empty:

> variable declare `PdfTemplate template;` and in OnOpenDocument method `template = cb.CreateTemplate(300, 800);` is create template

You merely create it and then add it. Thus, it is not surprising that adding that template at different positions makes no difference because an empty template effectively is invisible.

Now you ask

> can you explain how to put table in `pdftemplate` because right now i just create template

A `PdfTemplate` is derived from `PdfContentByte`, and to add structured content (`Paragraph`, `PdfPTable`, ...) to a `PdfContentByte` you use the `ColumnText` class, e.g. like this:

```
using (FileStream output = new FileStream(@"TemplateWithTable.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
using (Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4))
{
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
    document.Open();

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    table.AddCell("Test");
    table.AddCell("Table");

    PdfContentByte canvas = writer.DirectContent;
    PdfTemplate template = canvas.CreateTemplate(300, 800);
    Rectangle pageSize = document.PageSize;
    canvas.AddTemplate(template, pageSize.GetLeft(40), pageSize.GetBottom(200));

    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(template);
    ct.SetSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(100, 100, 300, 600));
    ct.AddElement(table);
    ct.Go();

    document.Close();
}
```

Comment: @OmkarP, I still think, though, that you actually are not interested in the `PdfTemplate` class at all. After all you say in your original question *"My task is to create a PDF template which contains multiple pages and multiple tables."* A `PdfTemplate`, on the other hand, represents just one piece of content to paste on any single page or other `PdfContentByte`, it is *not* paginated itself.